How do I eliminate this weird "landing page"? Is it possible?
I went to plain https://stackoverflow.com/ and I got this marketing-type screen:

When I click to (say) https://travel.stackexchange.com, or any other Prosus web page, I just get the normal page.  In the travel.SE example, I see the list of questions on travel.SE
Is there something I can do, so that when I enter "stackoverflow.com" I get the normal "stackoverflow.com" page  (i.e. the list of questions on stackoverflow.com)?

Proposed designs to update the homepage for logged-in users

TL;DR make https://stackoverflow.com/questions your new home page

From the latest edit on the announcement post... "If you have feedback after using it, see bugs, or notice anything wonky, please leave it on this post.". Also, I have no idea what you're asking in the second comment. The page at https://stackoverflow.com/ is canonically known as the "home page". The keyboard shortcut is even gh... "go home"

"Welcome back, Fattie" is probably exactly the kind of message which was intended by the misguided (in lack of a better word that will not cause this comment to get deleted and/or me to get suspended) project manager who came up with this useless banner...

I have no feedback, I see no bugs, and I see nothing wonky.  I was asking what it very clearly says in the title of this question.

(Indeed the question asked here is so obvious there appears to be dupes already, example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432148/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-the-new-question-obstructing-header )

The easiest way to get around this is just to open the questions page instead of the home page whenever you want to browse Stack Overflow.
If you don't want to do that, you can use this (very short) userscript to delete the three new widgets from the top:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide SO Widgets
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0.0
// @description  Hide the Stack Overflow home screen widgets.
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com
// @exclude      https://stackoverflow.com/.+
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("widgets-container").remove();


This leaves the big "Welcome back" banner in place, but I can live with that. (I left it because the div doesn't have an ID, which makes stable deletion annoying.) It also deletes the Watched Tags widget, which is unfortunate. And it won't bring back any of the good things that the home page changes removed, including:

Highlighting for questions with watched tags
Active/Hot/Week/Month sorting options
Custom Filters widget
Ignored Tags widget
Hot Network Questions
The naïve hope that Stack Exchange, Inc would notice the 182 downvotes on the announcement for this new home page and change course.


"The naïve hope that Stack Exchange, Inc would notice the 182 downvotes on the announcement for this new home page and change course"... lol, good one

Unfortunately the ?tab=interesting isn't available there... Even if far from perfect it was still relatively useful to find even incorrectly tagged questions in need of answers. The /questions/ page without tag filtering is mostly useless for non-reviewers. Having to follow the "big-tags" (like [js] in my case) will hide the actual (smaller) tags I'm interested in...

190 and probably still growing as more users find themselves victims of this.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/432018/874188 has a similar hack.

Ooh, and here. Thanks M!

We shouldn’t need a userscript to hide this trash design. SE please fix your website!

@Anerdw thanks for the info - it looks like the answer is "it's not possible".  the trouble is, the default page is the new childish one.  As you know, typically one just types (or types the first couple letters) of the string "stackoverflow" in to safari, and - now - the "childish page" pops up. It's not like one literally enters "a full url", I'm sure you know what I mean.  Overwhelmingly, one ends on what the web site wants the screen to be - and they want it to be the new "childish" one. It looks like there's no toggle or technical solution.  thanks for the info!!!

@tripleee seems to be 200s now!  You know I've just realized - "no, seriously" - Prosus is focussing on "gamification". Lol. I would guess, they've hired a "marketing gamification" consultant or group. The problem is when a site goes with consultants like that, it's a bit like the Browns and Watson or the Jets and that old guy they got as QB: it's such a trivially silly - yet incredibly expensive - mistake that the C-level of the corporation can't back down from the decision.  I still enjoy and use hourly SO but it's becoming just plain embarrassing which is a shame!

@Fattie You might be able to change your autocomplete to the questions page, either by using it a whole ton or by manually tweaking some value (not sure what the specific are). Also, setting something as a bookmark sometimes increases its autocomplete priority. Or use Thomas's solution.

@Anerdw I think the key fact is, within SO there IS NOT an option (for example, some setting in SO profile) along the lines of "do not use new design".  if so, that's the end of it.  Thanks though!

(American sports references don't work well with an international audience, though I think I can guess.)

It's not just the browser's autocomplete. There are many places in the UI where you can click on Stack Overflow, and aren't taken to the /questions page; so SO breaks useful expectations by deviating from the rest of the network.

I find this new front page absolute annoying as I use my custom filters to look for new questions.
As others stated, you could bookmark https://stackoverflow.com/questions. Or, you could also use a browser extension such as the Redirector Firefox extension:

