New (?) home page
Tonight I opened Stackoverflow and I was met by a new homepage, that

welcomed me back [unnecessary]
showed me my reputation [it's already in the top-right corner]
showed me my badge progress [not immediately interesting]
showed me not my saved filters [very bad decision]
showed me not "interesting" question [my tags were unrepresented wrt the previous home page]

Is it possible to switch to the homepage of yesterday?

NB I want not to discuss the features of the new home page, I just want to know if I can opt out of the new home page. I think my question should be reopened.

Provide feedback here: Proposed designs to update the homepage for logged-in users (not that they'll listen of course)

@Phil I think my question differs from the one you linked, because I want not to discuss the features of the new home page, I just want to know if I can opt out of the new home page

@gboffi that post initially discussed their proposed design and what users would want and now after those changes are implemented also acts as the place we can give feedback on the implementation. There's already a bunch of people who've left feedback there, it's best if we collect all that feedback in one place instead of fragmenting it.

@gboffi If you are asking about opting out, then there's already a post at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432077/how-do-i-eliminate-this-weird-landing-page-is-it-possible

Perhaps a gold badger in [[meta-tag:support]], or a passing moderator, could edit the dupes to include How do I eliminate this weird "landing page"? Is it possible?? (Unfortunately there are only 6 (non-moderator) of the former).
